# Get ALL property names

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In following code I get `true` meaning property `someMagic` is own property of `obj` at least in Chrome and Firefox.

But when I try to get full list of properties via `getOwnPropertyNames` returned array does NOT contain it in both browsers. In chrome I receive single property `constructor` and in FF the result is an empty array. Why?

**Is it possible to get *all* names?**

```js
var obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(window))
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('someMagic'))
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
```

```html
<div id="someMagic"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried `Object.keys(obj)`?

Comment: @kkesley, empty array in both.

Comment: @kkesley Those will be less than the `getOwnPropertyNames`

Comment: I guess this is because the `window` object is (or inherits from) a very quirky proxy-like exotic object. It's really magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bergi says in his comment, the `window` object is wrapped by something called [WindowProxy](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#windowproxy). Exactly as he says: exotic, proxy-like (and quirky and magic :-). A little more details from the specs:

> A WindowProxy is an exotic object that wraps a Window ordinary object, indirecting most operations through to the wrapped object. Each browsing context has an associated WindowProxy object. When the browsing context is navigated, the Window object wrapped by the browsing context's associated WindowProxy object is changed.
>
> The WindowProxy exotic object must use the ordinary internal methods except where it is explicitly specified otherwise below.

That last part about using ordinary internal methods "except where...explicitly specified" is key.

In the [EcmaScript 262 standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262), it specifies that `hasOwnProperty` uses `GetOwnProperty`. And `getOwnPropertyNames` uses `OwnPropertyKeys`. And note that both of these are overridden in `WindowProxy`:

> 7.4.5 [[GetOwnProperty]] ( P )
>
> 7.4.10 [[OwnPropertyKeys]] ( )

So the two properties you are using above are both using overridden, non-ordinary methods, rather than the "ordinary internal methods." And hence they are giving unusual results. There is even a warning under under `7.4.5 GetOwnProperty`, which warns of a "willful violation" of the specs:

> This is a willful violation of the JavaScript specification's invariants of the essential internal methods to maintain compatibility with existing Web content. See tc39/ecma262 issue #672 for more information. [JAVASCRIPT]

This [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) gives a little more of the history of how this strange behavior became part of the `HTML5` standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for in` to do this

EXAMPLE:

```
const obj =  {
  property: 'test',
  property2: 'test2'
}

for(property in obj)
  console.log('PROPERTY', property)
```

RESULT CONSOLE

```
const obj =  {
  property: 'test',
  property2: 'test2'
}

for(property in obj)
  console.log(property)

> "property"
> "property2"
```

Comment: I initially thought the same thing, but actually `for...in` doesn't work in his particular use case either. He's specifically asking about the `window` object and the quirky properties that get auto-added for elements with a `name` or `id` attribute.